# HEATMAP-Nan Layer, Kernel, Rows and Column

Tags: qgis, heat-map

My Friends,

My problem is with the Heatmap Plugin.

I have a 20.000 points in the map and when i want to heatmaping, the layer is NaN.

the village has 88 Km2 and is in the OpenStreetMap (wgs84 epsg:4326)

The values of heatmap are:

Radius: 300 meters

Rows: 50000
Column: 77712
*i prove with 500, 5000 and 50000 and i have the same problem (nan)
xcell: 0.00187496
ycell: 0.00187496

If someone can help me, please!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think your map needs to be in metres for heat map to work, try changing to 3857